# How can I use emailext plugin in jenkins agent?

Tags: jenkins, email-ext, jenkins-email-ext

I'm running Jenkins controller on ECS, and agent node is run on fargate.

```
    pipeline {
        agent {
            node {
                label 'agent-fargate'
            }
        }
...
```

and when test stage failed, I want to send email with groovy template.
I have template file, and I can access with ssh ECS node, but I can't modify the jenkins controller's container image (for now).

I put the template file in `resources/common/allure-report.template` in shared library code, and write it to agent in job(`writeFile(file: "${env.JENKINS_HOME}/email-templates/allure-report.template", text: libraryResource("common/allure-report.template"))`)
The file wrote succesfully, but `emailext` plugin can't find that file.

I put the template file in `/var/jenkins_home/email_templates/allure-report.template` using `scp` and `docker cp ---`, and it works.

---

but When Jenkins Controller rebooted, the file is removed, (and as I said, I can't modify container image at now.)
So I want to use email template file which in shared library's repository.

How Can I do that?